# c# Type parameters : How to Parse?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
public static T Process<T>(this string key)
        where T:bool,string, DateTime
    {
        var tType = typeof(T);

        if(tType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(key.InnerProcess());
        }
        else if(tType == typeof(bool))
        {
            return bool.Parse(key.InnerProcess());
        }
        else if(tType == typeof(string))
        {
            return key.InnerProcess();
        }
    }
```

It says it cannot typecast from bool to T, or datetime to T.. 
How to achieve this ?

**The `innerPrecess()` gives me a string. I want to parse it into the given parameter's type and then return it.**

Comment: Your type parameter constraints aren't going to work anyway. T needs to be *all* of them. Unfortunately, that's mutually exclusive here.

Comment: None of your constraints are valid: if you specify a type as constraint, it must either be an interface, or an unsealed class. `bool` and `DateTime` are structs, and `string` is a sealed class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ChangeType` for simpler:

```
public static T Process<T>( string key) where T: IConvertible
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(key.InnerProcess(), typeof (T));
}
```

Comment: +1, this will work for any type T which implements `System.IConvertible`.

Comment: Note that it's not `T` that needs to implement `IConvertible`, but rather the first argument to `ChangeType()`. Which will always be a `string` (and which does implement the interface.) Realistically, `T` has to be a type for which `IConvertible` provides a conversion, though there's no clean way to put that in a constraint.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't try to understand the code to prove that what you are returning *is* a `T`. The only way to do this involves adding a box/unbox (for the value-types, not the string), unfortunately:

```
return (T)(object)DateTime.Parse(...etc...);
```

Personally, I would suggest just using separate non-generic methods unless there is a very good reason to use generics here.